# MySql - Convert InnoDB to MyISAM Storage Engine of Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to convert database storage engine from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM` on `MySQL`?
I found so many sites which convert the storage engine of database table, but not for database.
[image: i attached screen shot for better understand]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you have already tried this ? [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)

Comment: I want to convert database not tables.This link you gave is for conversion of tables not database

Comment: Guys if this question helpful, you can upvote also not only answer...

Comment: Admin : just upboated !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert all tables from MyISAM into InnoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb)

Comment: Sorry to ask you but does the fact to convert innodb table to myisam could create issues or not ? I mean if I have innodb without foreign keys restrictions and alls features related. Currently I have innodb tables but I want to convert them as myisam because the innodb tables are used like if it was myisam ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't change the default storage engine for a database, but you can change it for the whole server using the `default-storage-engine` config setting.  Note that this will not actually change the storage engine for existing tables though, just for new ones created after the change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helps me & yes sorry for late reply.

Comment: @ArunVM - if so, please post an answer on how that can be done.  I know it can be done for the server, or for individual tables, but not for a database.

Answer (score 67):

use this!!

```
SET storage_engine=MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

-cheers!!

Comment: I want to convert InnoDB to MyISAM storage engine of database not table.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me a lot of time. When I did this on a Raspberry PI running MySQL (mariadb), the system finally stopped locking up when doing big inserts or updates. Literally 10x faster

Answer (score 19):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENGINE=INNODB
```

Answer (score 8):

Databases are just MySQL's way of doing namespaces, as such the database has no engine associated to it, only the tables have a storage engine. Which is why you can have a database with several different tables each having a different engine.

You will have to modify each table one by one to switch them to InnoDB.

Answer (score 5):

to make it permanent, add to my.cnf (few locations depending on context)

/etc/my.cnf

`default-storage-engine= MyISAM`

for safety, output the db list with
    show databases;

in my case, using php for quickie..

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','someadmin','somepass');
$dbs = array();
$dbs[] = 'test';
$dbs[] = 'myImportantDb';

foreach($dbs as $v){
    mysql_select_db($v);
    $q = mysql_query('show tables');
    $tables = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_row($q)){
            $tables[] = $r[0];
    }
    foreach($tables as $t){
        echo "do $v.$t\n";
        mysql_query('ALTER TABLE `'.$t.'` ENGINE=MyISAM;');
    }
}
mysql_close($db);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PhpMyadmin 4.5
Select the variable tab and find for
    **storage engine**
and Select Edit and type MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the storage engine through PhpMyAdmin. In the details view of the table. See the screenshot:

[Changing storage engine in PhpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guCqA.png)