# Mysql changing default engine

Tags: mysql

How to change the mysql engine to MYISAM. Now I am having mysql with INNODB but I want to change the engine to MYISAM. What i have to do?

```
CREATE TABLE `classifieds_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `template_prefix` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `enable_contact_form_upload` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `contact_form_upload_max_size` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1048576',
  `contact_form_upload_file_extensions` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'txt,doc,odf,pdf',
  `images_max_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `images_max_width` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1024',
  `images_max_height` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1024',
  `images_max_size` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1048576',
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `sortby_fields` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `classifieds_category_6223029` (`site_id`),
  KEY `classifieds_category_56ae2a2a` (`slug`),
  CONSTRAINT `site_id_refs_id_2d06e6c6` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `django_site` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I tried to change the engine here. but I don't want to change the every table. Is any settings is there to change engine commonly??

i also run the query like `SET default_storage_engine=MYISAM;` But no reaction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql - Convert InnoDB to MyISAM Storage Engine of Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280754/mysql-convert-innodb-to-myisam-storage-engine-of-database)

Comment: I am using mysql workbench...not php myadmin..

Comment: FYI, workbench and phpmyadmin are just frontends.

Comment: As fancyPants wrote, this is only the frontend, the commands are the same, you changed your default, now all newly created tables will be MYISAM, but all existing tables will have to be migrated separately (In the first comment you will find the commands and an example script to do this with php)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be a modest performance benefit, but issues of referential integrity, maintenance of constraints, etc. would surely outweigh this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the value of the variable `default_storage_engine` has no effect on existing tables. All it does, is to create new tables with the engine you specified in this variable when you don't specify it in your `create table` statement. It's just a default value.

Also keep in mind, that you have to distinguish between `global` and `session` variable values. To really have MyISAM as default whenever you create a new table, and not just for the current session, do it like this:

```
SET GLOBAL  default_storage_engine=MYISAM;
```

If you want to keep the variable to this value even after restarting the server, you have to put follwing line into your default file `my.cnf` under the section `[mysqld]`

```
default_storage_engine = MYISAM
```

To convert your current tables to MyISAM do this for every table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

But keep in mind, that you foreign key constraint will not work anymore, as MyISAM doesn't support it. It will not complain, it will just ignore it. So you better be sure, you know what you're doing :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accepted then by clicking the check. Here's a quick guide, how this site works, in case you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

1. Add  `default_storage_engine=MYISAM;` to my.cnf
2. Restart the mysql server

Comment: hi @Geetha for cnf plz check this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer