# Alter all database tables engine to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I want to use an sql query, to alter all my database tables engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.
I used the query below. Although it gives me a success message, it doesn t work. Still my table s Storage Engine is MyISAM.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB;') as ExecuteTheseSQLCommands
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'name_of_the_database' 
ORDER BY table_name DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**edit**: oh wait, you generated this kind of statements, but they did not work?

Comment: if I execute your sql statement (per table), it works. I want all tables at once. Using my sql query, I get a success, but no change to the Storage Engine

Comment: You statement only generates a list of results which look like SQL statements, but these statements are not actually executed. You should copy/paste the output of your SELECT to a `mysql` command, which will run them one by one.

Comment: Yes that s correct. So is there an sql query, to do this at once, no matter the number and names of database tables ?

Comment: Like I said in my previous answer, the easiest solution would be to copy/paste the output of your previous query  in a file, then do:

`mysql -u user -p pwd < yourfile.sql`

Answer (score 1):

- If you have knowledge in PHP then this script will help you:

  [How to convert all tables from MyISAM into InnoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb)
- If you have knowledge in Shell script then this link will help you:

  http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Shell+and+MySQL#ShellandMySQL-ConvertMyISAMtablestoInnoDB  (domain name changed by wiki owner)

Comment: Yes, that s the same like taking the results of my query and copy/paste them for execution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My solution - launch your mysql shell and paste:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME),'     
ENGINE=InnoDB;') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE ENGINE='MyISAM'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('MYSQL','INFORMATION_SCHEMA','PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA','SYS')
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mysql.conversions';
SOURCE /tmp/mysql.conversions;
```

Source 1: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-convert-all-mysql-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb-storage-engine/

Source 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014411/3882707

Comment: You should makes sure to exclude tables in system schemas `mysql`, `information_schema`, `performance_schema`, `sys`. In MySQL 5.x, most of the `mysql.*` system tables MUST use the MyISAM engine. In MySQL 8.0, they're InnoDB already, so no need to alter them.

Comment: Also you should put back-ticks around the schema names and table names, just in case someone has named their table the same as a reserved word. For example a table named `order` is pretty common.