# How to change varchar's length in all columns with known length?

Tags: mysql

I have many tables with columns of `varchar(45)`. Now I need them all to became `varchar(128)`. Is there a way to do it without manually examining all 40 tables?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb) that touches similar topic, but how to do it with columns?

Comment: Didn't meant to answer it myself, but while writing question I somehow simply did it, so sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain all columns that meets my needs, I can use:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_schema LIKE "my_schema_name" 
    AND data_type = "varchar"
    AND character_maximum_length < 50;
```

Now I need to use any programming language that can connect to MySQL, and in a loop execute:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(128);
```

Comment: why did your question say `varchar(256)` but your answer has `VARCHAR(128)`??... anyways good answer.

Comment: @amaster507 Corrected. Requirements changed between question and answer part and I missed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: NOTE: when you use MODIFY, the column_definition must include all of the attributes that should apply to the new column (other than index attributes). Attributes present in the original definition but not specified for the new definition are not carried forward. For example, if one of those columns was defined as `NOT NULL`, then after the MODIFY in your statement, the column will "lose" the NOT NULL attribute.

Comment: @spencer7593 Good point. I have 2 questions. 1) can you link the docs? With #anchor to that part? Maybe I'm mind-blind but I can't see it. 2) do you know a way around it?

Comment: (1) [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) There's no anchor for that section, it's buried deep under the ninth bullet under Usage Notes. It's the only occurrence of the phrase "must include" on the page; In Firefox or Chrome -> Find (Ctrl+F) "must include". (2) there's no workaround, other than pulling the other attributes and producing the full column_definition.

Comment: And don't forget to take a backup before trying this!