# MySQL change tables to InnoDB

Tags: mysql

I had an issue with Magento and ran a script that dropped my DB and then recreated the tables and data from a backup. However, when it did this, all the tables were created with the MyISAM Engine. Many of them are required to be InnoDB. So...I read this: [How to convert all tables from MyISAM into InnoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb)

But, when I try it give me this:

```
Your query produced 1 warnings.
Warning: Using storage engine MyISAM for table 'magadmin_assert'
```

And when I attempt to do it using HeidiSQL's interface, I can't select it from the Engine dropdown:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: run this **show engines;** and see what the output, are outputs contains innodb?

Comment: says InnoDB is disabled. How do I enable it? What vould have disabled it? I ran a `SET GLOBAL innodb-fast_shutdown=0` earlier

Comment: When I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, I get this:
`ERROR 1235 (42000): Cannot call SHOW INNODB STATUS because skip-innodb is defined`

Comment: There is NO `skip-innodb` in my my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enable innoDB engine in my.ini in your mysql installation directory then restart your mysql, follow steps in this [LINK](https://techjourney.net/enable-mysql-innodb-storage-engine-support-in-xampp-installation/)

I use xammp on windows and my.ini is:

```
# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Comment: There is NO skip-innodb in my my.cnf

Comment: if there is no that is OK, the reference link say you should comment it. but complete the next steps and restart your server then try to change your table engine.

Comment: Higher ups said to wait to reboot DB server.