# Import database problem in google SQL cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have already host of my wordpress website on Google Cloud Platform using Google Cloud Compute Engine. Now I want to split my existing wordpress database and move to Google SQL Cloud to improve my website performance.

I'm creating successfully SQL instance on Google Cloud SQL cloud. I refer to [this](https://geekflare.com/google-cloud-sql-wordpress/) link but I got error when I'm uploading my wordpress database backup.

After creating database on Google Cloud SQL  when I click on import button, it take few minutes and show `import failed : error 1031 (hy000) table storage engine for  wp_wcfm_daily_analysis doesn't have this option` error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're are you exporting your database? Are you trying to import them from a bucket?

Comment: Yes i'm import this from bucket. And then import in sql database. After import i got import failed : error 1031 (hy000) table storage engine for in google cloud.

Comment: Sorry Chris32. But this post is not helpfull for me. I'm using wordpress. So my wordpress database not import on Google sale cloud and your reference post is related to magento i'have already try this. But not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your import file there is the command that tries to change the storage engine from `InnoDB` to some other storage engine, probably to `MyISAM`.

As it is stated in the [CloudSQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#database_engines):

> InnoDB is the only supported storage engine for Second Generation instances because it is more resistant to table corruption than other MySQL storage engines, such as MyISAM.

You need to check in your sql file that you want to import, if you have the option : `ENGINE = MyISAM` attached to any `CREATE TABLE` command, and remove it.

You can also try to convert all your tables to InnoDB by using the following SQL code:

```
SET @DATABASE_NAME = 'name_of_your_db';

SELECT  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ENGINE=InnoDB;') AS sql_statements
FROM    information_schema.tables AS tb
WHERE   table_schema = @DATABASE_NAME
AND     `ENGINE` = 'MyISAM'
AND     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name DESC;
```

You can find here a [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb).

Comment: Sorry for late reply due very busy and hectic schedule. This error is my wordpress database engine problem. I'm create a new database and migrate a data from website using plugin in wordpress.